# Is it possible to force set cursor col-resize with pure css

Tags: javascript, css, windows, html

I have an issue with CSS property cursor on Windows operation system.
It seems that "col-resize" tries to invert the color of cursor depending on background.
The problem appears with gray color because one makes the cursor invisible.

```css
.test {
  cursor: col-resize;
  background: gray;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>
<body>
<div class='test'>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You could always use a custom cursor like this: cursor: url('path-to-image.png'), auto;

Comment: @imvain2 yep. It's true. But I want to avoid this solution.